# How to use downloaded blockchain on ubuntu?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I am using a fresh install of Bitcoin and have no wallet with coins at this time, and want to use the Bitcoind service in short time (loading blockchain using bitcoind will take days because of slow pc, can not wait for that also because PC can't run all day). So I decided to download the blockchain from http://eu1.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/.

But how do you use it? I am using Ubuntu 10.4 and Bitcoin 0.7.0. I already placed the downloaded files in .bitcoin directory and then run bitcoind but then it just started downloading the blockchain from the network, ignoring my downloaded files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That set of the blockchain data files doesn't contain the required index.